# Tried accessing nonexisting field (members) on node type (Group)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

facebook api 04-05-2018 exception:Tried accessing nonexisting field (members) on node type (Group). please help me

Answer (score 3):

Members - edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.